# Easiest way to deploy customized Lucene QueryParser onto Solr core

Tags: solr, lucene, query-parser

I have developed a customization to Lucene QueryParser by changing the QueryParser.jj grammar. One way to deploy this onto Solr is to revamp the Solr war file by compiling new lucene core.

On the other hand, a new query parser on Solr level can be deployed as a binary dependency (jar) into Solr core's lib directory, which is very convenient.

Is there a similar way to deploy my customization?
Could I deploy my lucene-core binary dependency into core's lib directory or somewhere else but the Solr war file?

UPD: The comments to the answer contain the thought process behind my implementation.

UPD2: I have written a blog post on my findings: http://dmitrykan.blogspot.fi/2014/03/implementing-own-luceneqparserplugin.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand you can write your own parser (with a new name), place this jar into the `lib` folder and add the corresponding `<queryParser>` to `solrconfig.xml`. See [an example of a query parser](http://www.lucenerevolution.org/2013/Implementing-Custom-Searc-Syntax-using-Solr-Lucene-and-Parboiled), implemented by John Berryman @JnBrymn.

Comment: That is quite smart. I need to double check it and if works will mark as answer, thanks!

Comment: the only caveat I see right now is: we already have our own query parser registered in solrconfig.xml. But, as long as Solr loads the new base parser from the lib directory I can inherit it instead of QueryParser class.

Comment: Yes, you don't have to rewrite the code completely. See, how [synonym_edismax](https://github.com/healthonnet/hon-lucene-synonyms) is extending `edismax` as well.

Comment: ok, I have done the CustomQueryParser.jj implementation which produces CustomerQueryParser.java. The next biggest thing is to wire it into the LuceneQParserPlugin. Looks like I need to do something similar to synonym_edismax implementation or find an even easier way.

Comment: for the notes: after the above mentioned implementation I have wired it all the way to the LuceneQParserPlugin.

Comment: I'm looking forward to reading a new great post about it from you! :)

Comment: further notes: wiring into the plugin worked. Somehow the default field gets unset.

Comment: In o.a.solr.parser.SolrQueryParserBase, in method getFieldQuery() there is check for the presence of a field or defaultField via checkNullField(field); But if field is null the remaining code produces NPE. => fixed by setting field=defaultField.

Comment: I'm trying to get my custom QParserPlugin loaded into solr cloud, but I can't get the config updated.  I've tried all kinds of things, but I'm just shooting blanks.  I'm using solr 5.4.1.  I'm also using the BLOB thing in zookeeper, but I'm not even getting the config to reload.  Oh, and the link to the example query parser, is broken. Thanks and Jesus bless!